# Django: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'product_obj' when running for loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to loop through a queryset, get the product object and remove the qty of items ordered from the product's stock amount.

This is how my model Looks

```
class CartOrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(CartOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_obj = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

And this is how it looks in the admin section
[image]

This is how i ran the forloop

```
@login_required
def PaymentSuccessView(request):
    ...
    order_items = CartOrderItem.objects.filter(order=order, order__payment_status="paid")
    for o in order_items.product_obj:
        print(o.title)  # print all the products title
        print(o.stock_qty)  # print the stock qty from the Product model
        # I want to substract the CartOrderItem's qty from the Product's stock qty
```

It then shows this error that says

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'product_obj'
```

This error is saying that the queryset for the `CartOrderItems` models does not have an attribute `"product_obj"`, but i clearly have a `'product_obj'` field in my `CartOrderItems`

---

This is how i wanted to substract the items qty from the product stock qty, i am not sure this would work and i haven't tried it because the error above would not allow me

```
for o in order_items.product_obj:
    o.product_obj.stock_qty -= o.qty
    o.save()
```

Comment: "This error is saying that the queryset for the CartOrderItems models does not have an attribute "product_obj"": it's actually the other way around. It's telling you that `order_items` is a `QuerySet`, not a `CartOrderItems` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order_items` is a `QuerySet` object and it clearly has no `product_obj` attribute.

You need to look at the loop part, because you are making very basic mistake.

```py
order_items = CartOrderItem.objects.filter(order=order, order__payment_status="paid")
for order_item in order_items:
    order_item.product_obj.stock_qty -= o.qty
    order_item.product_obj.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over `order_items` first to get the query set results, then access the `.product_obj` attribute for each item returned by the queryset.

```py
    order_items = CartOrderItem.objects.filter(order=order, order__payment_status="paid")
    for cart_order in order_items:
        product = cart_order.product_obj
        product.stock_qty -= cart_order.qty
        product.save()
```